# javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption exception

Tags: java, android, exception, encryption, aes

I am trying to decrypt a string in android. I keep getting the following exception:

```
08-21 03:56:56.700: W/System.err(4208): javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption
08-21 03:56:56.700: W/System.err(4208):     at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCEBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(JCEBlockCipher.java:697)
08-21 03:56:56.700: W/System.err(4208):     at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1106)
08-21 03:56:56.700: W/System.err(4208):     at com.dharani.android.legalplex.BusinessLayer.BLCommonOperations.decrypt(BLCommonOperations.java:284)
08-21 03:56:56.700: W/System.err(4208):     at com.dharani.android.legalplex.BusinessLayer.BLCommonOperations.decryptAndgetFailCountFromPreferences(BLCommonOperations.java:144)
08-21 03:56:56.700: W/System.err(4208):     at com.dharani.android.legalplex.PresentationLayer.TransparentActivity.onCreate(TransparentActivity.java:112)
08-21 03:56:56.700: W/System.err(4208):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
08-21 03:56:56.700: W/System.err(4208):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
08-21 03:56:56.700: W/System.err(4208):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
08-21 03:56:56.700: W/System.err(4208):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
08-21 03:56:56.700: W/System.err(4208):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
08-21 03:56:56.700: W/System.err(4208):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
08-21 03:56:56.700: W/System.err(4208):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-21 03:56:56.700: W/System.err(4208):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-21 03:56:56.700: W/System.err(4208):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
08-21 03:56:56.700: W/System.err(4208):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 03:56:56.700: W/System.err(4208):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-21 03:56:56.700: W/System.err(4208):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
08-21 03:56:56.700: W/System.err(4208):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
08-21 03:56:56.700: W/System.err(4208):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The encrypt and decrypt methods are:

```
public  String encrypt(String message) throws Exception
{
    String salt = SharedVariables.globalContext.getString(R.string.EncryptionKey);
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(salt.getBytes(), "AES");
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(message.getBytes());
    String encrypted=Base64.encodeToString(encVal, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encrypted;
}

public  String decrypt(String message) throws Exception
{
    String salt = SharedVariables.globalContext.getString(R.string.EncryptionKey);
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(salt.getBytes(), "AES");
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] decordedValue = Base64.decode(message.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
    String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
    return decryptedValue;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide some test data that causes this error when you'd call it like this: `decrypt(encrypt(testData))`. Also include the actual encryption key value you used.

Comment: @ssl Good to hear that you found an answer to your question.  You should post it as an answer, along with an explanation of what needed to be changed, and then you can accept it.  This helps other users find it in the future, and lets them know what worked for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the solution.Following is new code that worked for me

```
// Encryption
public  String encrypt(String message) throws Exception
{
    String message1=Base64.encodeBytes(message.getBytes(),Base64.NO_OPTIONS);
    String salt = SharedVariables.globalContext.getString(R.string.EncryptionKey);
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(salt.getBytes(), "AES");
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(message1.getBytes());
    String encrypted=Base64.encodeToString(encVal, Base64.NO_OPTIONS);
    return encrypted;
}

//Decryption    
public String decrypt(String message) throws Exception
{
    String salt = SharedVariables.globalContext.getString(R.string.EncryptionKey);
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(salt.getBytes(), "AES");
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] decordedValue = Base64.decode(message.getBytes(), Base64.NO_OPTIONS);
    byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
    String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
    String decoded=new String(Base64.decode(decryptedValue,Base64.NO_OPTIONS));
    return decoded;
}
```

Comment: You need to explain what you changed, dont just post code without explanation.

Comment: @sravanalakshmi-sunkara there's no Base64.NO_OPTIONS available:

- no_padding, no_wrap, no_close only

Comment: **Warning**: this code uses ECB, using a hidden, default string ("AES" is "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding" for most providers). ECB mode is **not secure**.

Answer (score 1):

`salt.getBytes()` should be `salt.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT)`