# AES Algorithm for audio files in Android

Tags: android, cryptography, aes

Hi I am working on AES encryption and decryption in my project.

I have a .mp4 file which is encrypted using "AES/CBC/pkcs5padding".

I have the key and iv values which is used to encrypt the first 256 bytes of the audio file.

I need to decrypt the file's first 256 bytes using the same algorithm , key and iv values.

I have followed some links ([link1](http://blog.dealforest.net/2012/03/ios-android-per-aes-crypt-connection/),[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261252/javax-crypto-illegalblocksizeexception-last-block-incomplete-in-decryption-de)).

I got a audio player demo and tried to implement my part(AES encryption and decryption) as demo.

Below I explained the code what I have done.

This method reads the data from encrypted file which is under res/raw folder.

```
private void readFile() throws IOException, InvalidKeyException,
        NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
        InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
        BadPaddingException {

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    /*
     * InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(
     * getResources().getIdentifier("raw/encrypted", "raw",
     * getPackageName())); String text = "";
     * 
     * int size = is.available(); byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
     * is.read(buffer);
     */

    InputStream inStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(
            R.raw.encrypted);

    // get string from file

    byte[] music = new byte[256];
    for (int i = 0; i <= inStream.available(); i = i + 255) {
        music = convertStreamToByteArray(inStream, i);
        byte[] bytesToWrite = new byte[256];

        bytesToWrite = music;
        if (i == 0) {
            bytesToWrite = AES256Cipher.decrypt(iv.getBytes("UTF-8"),
                    key.getBytes("UTF-8"), music);
            // writeFirstSetOfBytes("decrypted.mp4");
        }

        writeFirstSetOfBytes(bytesToWrite);

    }
}
```

the decrypt method got from the [link1](http://blog.dealforest.net/2012/03/ios-android-per-aes-crypt-connection/). Here I passed the key and iv values mentioned above.

```
public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] ivBytes, byte[] keyBytes,
            byte[] textBytes) throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
            InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException,
            IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {

        AlgorithmParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
        // SecretKeySpec newKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,
                new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES"), ivSpec);
        return cipher.doFinal(textBytes);
    }
```

This method used to get the byte array from the input stream.

```
public static byte[] convertStreamToByteArray(InputStream is, int size)
        throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buff = new byte[256];
    int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    while ((i = is.read(buff, size, buff.length)) > 0) {
        baos.write(buff, 0, i);
    }

    return baos.toByteArray(); // be sure to close InputStream in calling
                                // function
}
```

This method writes the received byte array into a destination file(decrypted.mp4)

```
private void writeFirstSetOfBytes(byte[] byteToWrite) {

    File file = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
            "/decrypted.mp4");
    FileOutputStream stream = null;
    if (!file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // writing data into file
    try {
        stream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        stream.write(byteToWrite);
        stream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I am getting the following error.

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length
```

How can I achieve my requirement ?

1. How do I decrypt the first 256 bytes of data only?
2. Is there any code behaves wrongly ?
3. Is there any third party library avilable ?

If need more clarification, kindly let me know.

Comment: Just a sidenote. The `decrypt()` routine expects `iv` and `key` as raw bytes, but your `readFile()` routine seems to convert them from some text representation. Are you sure you aren't passing a string of hexadecimal characters instead of raw bytes?

Comment: I really don't know where to start. Your stream handling is completely incorrect - including both loops, you are using `i = i + 255`, CBC mode is probably not a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

According to Wikipedia, PKCS#5 is a special variant of PKCS#7 that is defined for exactly 64-bit blocks (while PKCS#7 works for any block size), but AES uses 128-bit blocks only (or larger, but this was not included in the standard), thus the mismatch. Try another padding scheme.

Comment: Eh, no. See my answer [here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9043/what-is-the-difference-between-pkcs5-padding-and-pkcs7-padding), including the Java specifics.

Comment: @owlstead Believe it or not, but your answer on Crypto was exactly one of the sources I based my conclusion on. :-) Particularly, the line: “PKCS#5 padding can not be used for AES”. The rule that the library should not actually differentiate between PKCS#5 and PKCS#7 is just a formal regulation — one cannot be certain that a specific version of specific library adheres to this rule, unless explicitly verified, and that was exactly that I recommended to check in first place, the more so that this check would be trivial. And it is a good idea to correct the improper identifier anyway.

Comment: I'm of course honored to be the source of your answer, but "Some cryptographic libraries such as the SUN provider in Java indicate PKCS#5 where PKCS#7 should be used - "PKSC5Padding" should have been "PKCS7Padding"." is also part of that answer. In other words, if you specify PKCS#5 then actually PKCS#7 padding is used.