# How to decrypt a text?

Tags: java, android, encryption

I am developing an application, where I am encrypting and decrypting a text entered by the user.
But, I am getting the following error:

> javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in
>   decryption

below is my code for encryption and decryption. Encryption works perfectly, while I am getting this error while decrypting. Please refer the code below:

```
    public static String fncEncrypt(String strClearText, String strKey) throws Exception{
        String strData = "";
        try {
            SecretKeySpec sKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(strKey.getBytes(), "Blowfish");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sKeySpec);
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(strClearText.getBytes());
            strData = new String(encrypted);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return strData;
    }   
    public static String fncDecrypt(String strEecrypted, String strKey) throws Exception {    
        String strData = "";
        try {
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(strKey.getBytes(), "Blowfish");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
            byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(strEecrypted.getBytes());
            strData = new String(decrypted);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
        return strData;
    }
```

Please respond if you have a solution for this.

Comment: always try to google your problem with error log instead of post your question.

Comment: byte[] <-> String is not a systematically fully reversible process. Some sequences get transformed into characters that have several representations, and vice-versa. Use a fully reversible representation, such as base64

Answer (score 0):

You should decode the string instead of encoding the platform specific representation of the string, right at the start of your method.

```
byte[] base64TextToDecrypt = Base64.decodeBase64(textToDecrypt);
```

or more precisely:

```
byte[] bytesToDecrypt = Base64(base64TextToDecrypt);
```

if you name your variables correctly.

In general, each time you (feel like you have to) use the String.getBytes(): byte[] method or the  String(byte[]) constructor you are likely doing something wrong. You should first think about what you are trying to do, and specify a character-encoding if you do need to use it.

In your case, the output in the converted variable is probably character-encoded. So you you could use the following fragment:

```
String plainText = new String(converted, Charset.forName("UTF8"));
System.out.println(plainText);
```

instead of what you have now.

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13274072/8416317

Answer (score 0):

`String` class method `getBytes()` or `new String(byte bytes[])` encode / decode with `Charset.defaultCharset().name()`, and some encrypted data would be ignored by encoding with special charset.

you could directly return byte[] by `fncEncrypt` and input byte[] to `fncDecrypt`. or encode result with `BASE64`.

```
public static byte[] fncEncrypt(String strClearText, String strKey) throws Exception{
    byte[] encrypted = null;
    try {
        SecretKeySpec sKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(strKey.getBytes(), "Blowfish");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sKeySpec);
        encrypted = cipher.doFinal(strClearText.getBytes());

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return encrypted;
}

public static String fncDecrypt(byte[] ecrypted, String strKey) throws Exception {

    String strData = "";
    try {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(strKey.getBytes(), "Blowfish");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(ecrypted);

        strData = new String(decrypted);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return strData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is when you use `new String(encrypted)` it will not fully encode the bytes to string. Try the code below

```
public static byte[] fncEncrypt(String strClearText, String strKey) throws Exception{
    SecretKeySpec sKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(strKey.getBytes(), "Blowfish");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sKeySpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(strClearText.getBytes());
    return encrypted;
}

public static String fncDecrypt(byte[] encrypted, String strKey) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(strKey.getBytes(), "Blowfish");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
    return new String(decrypted);
}
```

You can encrypt and decrypt using the code below

```
String message = "Hello!";
byte[] encrypted = fncEncrypt(message, "key");
String decrypted = fncDecrypt(encrypted, "key");
System.out.println(decrypted);
```

Comment: It works fine on my PC. There should not be a problem. I have updated my code including the usage.